# Responsive Web Design and high resolution displays (iPhone 4/5)

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design

I have recently started toying around with responsive web design and have done a basic test here:

http://test.studev.net/

It works fine in a desktop browser however I am getting a little confused on how to deal with the smallest width design when loaded on a high resolution device for example retina displays on iPhones. Because of this type of display it means for example size 16px which is normal to read on a desktop is impossible to read on an iPhone 4/5.

How is this usually dealt with?

Comment: Have you considered just leaving the base font-size alone and using relative units (like `em`) for adjusting the font-size of larger/smaller elements?

Comment: Could you explain a little more on how to do that?

Comment: The jist of it is that you leave your "normal" text at the default font-size.  When you need bigger or smaller, you modify it by a percentage:  http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/GjDwe.  Also useful reading:  http://kyleschaeffer.com/user-experience/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/ and http://blog.cloudfour.com/the-ems-have-it-proportional-media-queries-ftw/

Comment: To me @cimmanon 's answer is the only right one. Every size measurement in responsive design should be based in relative `em`s rather than fixed `px`s. The latter will render the text very small on high pixel density screens, because in that world pixels are particularly teeny tiny things.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well either if you want to make the text smaller on mobile or bigger you would do

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    font-size: 10px; /* Smaller */
}
```

or

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    font-size: 20px; /*Larger*/
}
```

And make sure you have this in your `<HEAD>` tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Or you can also disable zooming like so:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

And for IE10 support, try:

```
@-ms-viewport{
    width:device-width
}
```

Comment: Users typically do not like it when you disable zooming (`maximum-scale=1`).

Comment: That meta viewport code seems to of done it, making everything on my iPhone much more readable using the same font-size on the desktop and mobile device. Cheers.

Comment: It should be noted that IE10 does not honor the viewport meta tag.  They're supporing the CSS `@viewport` rule instead:  http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/an-introduction-to-meta-viewport-and-viewport/

Comment: Ou Em Gee, your answer just freed me from a head ache! :D

Comment: @cimmanon It's not only that "users typically do not like it when you disable zooming" but people with poor sight simply will **not** be able to read your content. Don't do it without a really valid reason.

Comment: @tomasz86 I simply cannot think of a valid reason. I absolutely hate it when a website disables zooming and I'm in my phone trying to see something better. It's really annoying.

Comment: +1 for disable zooming, it let me to get rid of auto zooming when user focus on inputs, however user can change the default setting always. In chrome mobile browser there is an option in accessibility section to do that.

Comment: This fixed it for me: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">  But why?

Answer (score 6):

You can choose the size of the font according to the screen-width:

```
    /* Large desktop */
    @media (min-width: 1200px) {
        font-size: 18px;
    }

    /* Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop */
    @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
        font-size: 16px;
    }

    /* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */
    @media (max-width: 767px) {
        font-size: 14px;
    }

    /* Landscape phones and down */
    @media (max-width: 480px) {
        font-size: 12px;
    }
```

To make sure your layout stretch on the mobile screen you have to use the viewport meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

This meta tag needs to be inside the head tag. The "device-width" will be the maximum pixels your screen can show. You can also set a constant value there (600px).

The initial-scale=1 means it will be zoomed automatically to 100%. (0.5 => 50%)

Comment: So this would make the text smaller the smaller the device? This is kind of the opposite of the problem, the text needs to be bigger on a high resolution device, the problem with simply just making the text much larger when the max-width is for example 480px or 767px is that if a desktop browser window is narrowed down to this size then the text becomes huge.

Comment: Then you would just make the text smaller on a smaller media query.

Comment: It will make the text smaller on a smaller resolution. usually smaller resolution != smaller screen, just less pixels in it.

When you use the responsive design you add the meta tag viewport. It will "stretch" the layout on the entire screen and 16px for font-size will be good enough. 

Now days, some mobile browsers enlarge the content font size no matter what the "font-size" value is, so it would be more readable.

Comment: Meta tag viewport? How do I implement this?

Comment: I will add it to my answer