# Is there any difference between iPhone 4 and iPhone 5 when I use media queries?

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I know that iphone 5's resolution is 1136 x 640 px and iphone 4's 960 x 640 px. But are there differences in media queries when I build a responsive website?

So how can I determine is it a small screen netbook, or a new iphone 5 with high resolution?

Comment: Why do you need to determine that?

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16069856/responsive-web-design-and-high-resolution-displays-iphone-4-5

Comment: So I mean I would like to hide advertises for mobile users, but not for netbooks with small resolution.

`@media (max-width: 1136px) {
#advertise { display:none; }
}`

..but this code will hide the advertise div on all devices with this resolution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this site](http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/#iPhone), the difference is with the max-device-width:

In iphone4 it's 480px

In iphone5 it's 568px

### iphone4

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) { /* STYLES GO HERE */}
```

### iphone5:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) { /* STYLES GO HERE */ }
```

...and both have  Device-pixel-ratio: 2 so

iphone4 has screen height= 960px (Actual Pixels) and

iphone5 has screen height= 1136px (Actual Pixels)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have any luck with Danield's method, but I personally use this:

```
@media screen and (max-width:768px){
    /* iPad 2 and under */
}
@media screen and (max-width:375px){
    /* iPhone 6 and under */
}
@media screen and (max-width:320px){
    /* iPhone 5 and under */
}
@media screen and (max-device-width:320px) and (max-device-height:480px){
    /* iPhone 4 and under */
}
```

and if you need, iPhone 5 can also use:

```
@media screen and (max-device-width:320px) and (device-height:568px){
    /* iPhone 5 only */
}
```