# How to handle the different resolution (Retina & HDs) in mobile device?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, screen-resolution

I'm having different CSS files for different layout (Phone & Tablet). Since I have added styling in tablet view based on the view I get on my **Samsung Note 8 with resolution 1200x800**.

But when I run this application on **Samsung Galaxy tab750 with resolution 1920x1080**, I get smaller layout with smaller fonts since I have adjusted the fonts and layout based on Note 8.

So I get the suggestion to add the another CSS file for handling this. Next, when our QA tried running the application on iPad (**Retina Display 2048x1536**), again the third CSS is even small in it.

In 2012, there was a single tablet with a 2,560x1,600 resolution. In 2013, there were at least six. I suspect we'll see even more in 2014 (http://ces.cnet.com/8301-35302_1-57615742/tablets-at-ces-2014-the-calm-before-the-storm/#ixzz2nhc1BlAw).

With respect of this post [Responsive Web Design and high resolution displays (iPhone 4/5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16069856/responsive-web-design-and-high-resolution-displays-iphone-4-5),

We would be using media queries for required resolutions,

```
/* Large desktop */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    font-size: 18px;
}

/* Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
    font-size: 16px;
}

/* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    font-size: 14px;
}

/* Landscape phones and down */
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

So my concern is can we handle this scenario, without going on adding more and more CSS and media queries, if so please suggests.

Comment: It depends on the design you’re trying to achieve. On the web, it’s generally a bad idea to make layouts that assume a specific resolution — as you’ve noticed, the internet can and will be accessed on devices with *any* resolution. It’s impossible (and possibly off-topic for Stack Overflow) to tell you in general how to design layouts that work on different resolutions, but if you’ve got a specific question about the layout you’re working on, do show us.

Answer (score 2):

There are [a number of media-query based ways](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=media%20query%20detect%20retina%20screen&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&gws_rd=cr&ei=KumyUp6MLoyThgfSiYHYCA) of detecting high-density/retina devices.

I personally tend to use this, which seems to capture the vast majority of devices:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
    screen and (max--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
    screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {}
```

Totally personal preference though!

Do bear in mind that - to the most part - 'high density' screens (rather than just high-resolution) report themselves as their non-HD resolution for the purpose of media queries.

For example: the Retina Apple iPads have an actual screen-resolution of 2,048 by 1,536, but still reports as 1,024 by 768px.  Thus, the same screen-width/height media queries will capture the iPad 4 (retina) as the iPad 2 and - apart from being a little more blurry in the case of the older iPad - will look the same.

You can combine the media query I've included above with width/height to get a much more granular target on specifically-HD devices if you wish.

One very important exception to this is high-density display devices running Windows 8 Mobile which has a [known bug](http://timkadlec.com/2013/01/windows-phone-8-and-device-width/) with correctly reporting the viewport.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm already using the media queries. But my concern, is that i have already delivered the application handling upto device(1920x1080). Then if the user tends to run the application on a device(2048x1536), then that's sure that user is going to get a smaller layout. And if we need to handle this resolution, then again we need to build another version of the application. So my question is based on this. Can we do something, so that if we need to run my application on 2048x1536, then it should scale the layout so i would get the same look as i get it on 1920x1080 device.